# IOS scrolling issues (elastic scroll and bounce)

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css

I have developed a site that has a fixed footer and header.
The content is also fixed (but that is only because the footer and header can be hidden, but I won't be showing that in my example).
The issue I have is with iPhones and iPads. They are two issues I have had.
Once is it allowing me to drag the header and footer past the confines of the body/html showing whitespace (no idea why they do this) and the other issue is it stopping scrolling as soon as I let go with my finger. 
The latter seems to be solvable by doing this:

```
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: scroll;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

Although I have read that this is not a supported CSS attribute, it does seem to do the trick.
The second issue I have tried to solve with JavaScript by making the **header** and **footer** non-scrollable, but it doesn't seem to work properly.
The JavaScript is simple enough:

```
function disableElasticScroll(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
};
```

which I can put on an element like this:

```
ontouchmove="disableElasticScroll(event)"
```

This does not have the desired effect.
I have set up a codepen to highlight the issue. If you have an ipad, have a look. First drag the content inside the **.content** area. That works nicely (thanks the the -webkit solution). If you then try and drag the **.header** or **.footer** you will notice that you can't drag it and no scrolling is happening (again this is good and is due to the JavaScript), but if you try to then scroll the **.content** again, you will notice that it drags the entire page and does the elastic scroll rubbish.

https://codepen.io/r3plica/pen/LzRQaZ

Comment: I would have thought loads of people would be able to answer this....Is my description not good enough? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to do this so that you don't have to fix the scrolling container. Try positioning your header and footer with a fixed position then padding the body of your page by the height of those elements. This way your page will scroll normally without any hacks. It might look something like this:

```
body {
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}
header.global {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
}
footer.global {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
}
```

Comment: I will give that a shot today and mark this as the answer if it works

Answer (score 0):

```
html, body {
 position: fixed;
}
```

try setting this css property and see if it works.
It solves the elastic scrolling effect on the body.

[Sample page](http://jsbin.com/wahebiduje/2/edit?html,output)

[Output to test on ipad](http://output.jsbin.com/wahebiduje/)